# Spring - using factory beans in configuration?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

What is the correct way to use factory beans in `@Configuration` classes?

Suppose I have the following for `SessionFactory`:

```
@Bean
public AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    AnnotationSessionFactoryBean factory = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
    // set up properties etc.
    return factory;
}
```

Right now this method returns a bean factory which does not implement `SessionFactory`. If I use it in another bean with `@Autowired` as `SessionFactory`, it works just fine and obtains it from bean factory:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Autowired SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    // ...
}
```

I guess that's OK.

However, it becomes an issue if I want to use the `SessionFactory` in the same configuration class:

```
@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager man = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    // Ideal - doesn't work because sessionFactory() return type doesn't match:
    // SessionFactory sessionFactory = sessionFactory();
    // Is this one correct?
    // SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) sessionFactory().getObject();
    man.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    return man;
}
```

What is The Right Way to implement this kind of dependency?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`@Configuration` approach is still relatively fresh and it has some rough edges. Factory beans are one of them. So the is no *Right Way*, at least I am not aware of any. Maybe future Spring releases will handles this case somehow. For now, this is my preferred way:

```
@Bean
public AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean() {
    AnnotationSessionFactoryBean factory = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
    // set up properties etc.
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
   return (SessionFactory) sessionFactoryBean().getObject();
}
```

And use `sessionFactory()` method whenever needed. If you want to call the `sessionFactoryBean().getObject()` several times for some reason (e.g. when `FactoryBean` does not return singletons), remember to use `@Scope` annotation. Otherwise Spring will make sure `sessionFactory()` is called only once and cache the result.

Spring is intelligent enough to perform all required initialization after calling `@Bean` method and before returning the bean itself. So `InitializingBean`, `DisposableBean`, `@PostConstruct`, etc. are all recognized and treated properly. In fact, I was always finding calling `afterPropertiesSet` a bit of a hack, because it is the container responsibility.

---

Also there is a second method advised in [Spring Datastore Document - Reference Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-document/docs/1.0.0.M3/reference/html/#d0e1040), which at first sight looks a bit inconsistent, but works great:

```
@Resource
private Mongo mongo;

@Bean
MongoFactoryBean mongo() {
     return new MongoFactoryBean();
}
```

So factory is created using `@Bean` method but the bean created by the factory can be obtained using autowired field. Clever.

Comment: Doesn't it require afterPropertiesSet()?

Comment: Nope, Spring is intelligent enough to perform all required initialization after calling `@Bean` method and before returning the bean itself. So `InitializingBean`, `DisposableBean`, `@PostConstruct`, etc. are all recognized and treated properly. In fact, I was always finding calling `afterPropertiesSet` a bit of a hack, because it is the container responsibility.

Comment: Neat workaround. It rather detracts from the point of using `@Configuration`, though, which is to perform your wiring using actual method calls. Still, I like it.

Comment: *@skaffman* - true, that's what I meant saying it is inconsistent. Moreover, it doesn't seem to work when factory bean declaration and `@Resource` are in the same `@Configuration` class (*Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?*)

Comment: I realize this is an old answer but for others this still makes sense. I ran into an issue that only occurred when doing a hot redploy of our application. It turned out that one of our developers had migrated some old XML-based spring configuration to Java configuration. He used the proper Spring factory beans, but returned the factoryBean.getObject() instance instead of the factorybean instance from the @Bean methods. This in turn meant that our mbeanserver, rmiregistry etc. were NOT destroyed when redeploying. After changing the Java code to return the factoryBean everything worked great :-)

Comment: I think it's a better alternative of the 2nd approach: `@Bean @Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory factory) ...`. This way the reference to the dependency bean remains local to the method that creates the dependent bean. (Similarly to as using `sessionFactory()` would be local to it, if it weren't a `FactoryBean`.)

Answer (score 0):

I found an example of this on the [Spring forums](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?82677-How-to-make-factoryBeans-work-with-javaConfig).

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = 
              new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
    // ...configuration code here...
    sessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return sessionFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```

Comment: That's a bad idea. If you do this, the lifecycle of the `FactoryBean` will not be managed as it should be, and your app won't shut down cleanly. In this particular example, you can avoid the issue by using `@Bean(destroyMethod="close")`, but it's not great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it the following way:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class LoginServiceTest {

  @Configuration
  public static class Config {

    @Bean
    public HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean loginServiceProxy() {
      HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean proxy = new HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean();
      proxy.setServiceInterface(LoginService.class);
      proxy.setServiceUrl("http://localhost:8080/loginService");
      return proxy;
    }

  }

  @Inject
  private LoginService loginService;

  @Test
  public void testlogin() {
    loginService.login(...);
  }
}
```