# Spring JavaConfig + JAX-WS Client

Tags: spring, jax-ws

I need to create a webservice client to get sportsdata.
But I'm getting an exception when trying to `@Autowired sportsdata`.

**Exception:**

`org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [de.openligadb.schema.SportsdataSoap] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

**JavaConfig**:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example", excludeFilters = { @Filter(Configuration.class) })
public class MainConfig {
    private @Value("${openligadb.wsdlDocumentUrl}") String wsdlDocumentUrl;
    private @Value("${openligadb.endpointAddress}") String endpointAddress;
    private @Value("${openligadb.namespaceUri}") String namespaceUri;
    private @Value("${openligadb.serviceName}") String serviceName;

    @Bean
    public JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean sportsdata() throws MalformedURLException {
        JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean ret = new JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean();
        ret.setWsdlDocumentUrl(new URL(wsdlDocumentUrl));
        ret.setServiceInterface(SportsdataSoap.class);
        ret.setEndpointAddress(endpointAddress);
        ret.setNamespaceUri(namespaceUri);
        ret.setServiceName(serviceName);
        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer ret = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        ret.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("application.properties"));
        return ret;
    }
}
```

And yes: I know of `@PropertySource` but I need to create a bean for it to use it later in my Controller as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a `FactoryBean` interoperability problem with `@Configuration`. Take a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446857/spring-using-factory-beans-in-configuration) for details.

The short version is to add a bean explicitly to your configuration.

```
@Bean
public SportsdataSoap sportsdataSoap() throws ... {

    return (SportsdataSoap) sportsdata().getObject();
}
```

Comment: Don't forget possibly calling `afterPropertiesSet()` before that.

Comment: Or I could modify the method to return SportsdataSoap directly (`return (SportsdataSoap) ret.getObject()`)?!

Comment: Nope, Spring needs to initialise the FactoryBean, which is done with *its* `@Bean`. If you call `getObject()` directly before that happens, you'll get a null back AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks, it worked very well! @SotiriosDelimanolis there was no need to call afterPropertiesSet.

Comment: As for the Spring 4.0.X version you can define only JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean bean